# Are morph targets in three.js gpu powered?

Tags: three.js, gpu, shader, vertex-shader

I have thousands of these shapes:

```
var someShape = new THREE.Shape( somePts );
var extrudedGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(someShape, {depth: 1, bevelEnabled: false});
var extrudedMesh = new THREE.Mesh(extrudedGeometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: getRandomColor(), transparent: true}));
```

Each one of these shapes will morph into a different shape with the same amount of vertices. I was thinking of using morph targets, do they run on the gpu?

Is a morph target in three.js implemented behind the scenes as a vertex shader or if I'm trying to do this for thousands of objects should I create my own vertex shader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was thinking of using morph targets, do they run on the gpu?

Yes, morph target animation is a form of vertex displacement which is implemented in the vertex shader. Most built-in materials like `MeshPhongMaterial` support it by including the respective shader chunks. As a user, you just have to set [.morphTargets](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.morphTargets) to `true` in order to notify the renderer that a specific material should use morph targets.

`three.js R104`